# How can I count every custom function usage for a user of an add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function, google-apps-script-addon

I made an add-on with a custom function that calls an API. My plan is: when a user installs add-on I give him 20 free calls. Can I count every usage of the custom function server-side?

UPD: I've found a solution. Today I set up a function to change a number of calls pushing every call to Firebase. [This article](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/read-and-write-data-in-firebase-from-apps-script) helped a lot to understand everything.

Comment: it is possible to use counter after authentication in the server function.

Comment: It'd be best to store that data in a [separate database](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc). However, you could also try to store this info in the [PropertiesService's UserProperty](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) (*not recommended* because of [limited storage space](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations).)

Comment: @AryanFirouzyan can you please show me any examples?

Comment: @ChrisWI tried to save it to UserProperty, but got a lot ot error (Service invoked too many times in a short time: properties. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls.). Even Utilities.sleep(1000) doesn't help.

Comment: @IgorStefurak By custom function are you referring to functions to be used in Google Sheets formulas?

Comment: @Rubén yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script can't count custom function usage per user as they are ran anonymously.

Reference

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: I already implemented counting with UserProperty. But getting «Service invoked too many times in a short time: properties» error when there are too many users.

Comment: @IgorStefurak That problem should be posted as a new question.